# How to delete list item inside document in firebase firestore in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

[image: I have a list stored inside a document of Firestore. I want to delete a specific item from the list how to delete this item!]

I have visited many websites but did not find a suitable solution. Anyone can give me a reference about this problem.

Comment: So would you like to delete a single item from the `diaryUploadModelList` array from the selected (`BpGR...sB6r`) document?  If yes, which one?

Comment: yes brother @AlexMamo!!!

Comment: Which one of them?

Comment: @AlexMamo on the basis of user click on list item

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer right away.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks in advance brother!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete an element from your `BpGR...sB6r` array, you have to pass to the `arrayRemove()` method the entire data of the element you want to delete. It will **not** work if you just pass partially data.

In your case, to remove the first object entirely, for example, it means that you'll have to create a HashMap that will contain **all** data of the element and pass that to the update() method. For Android, this will look like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> elementToDelete = new HashMap<>();
elementToDelete.put("audioUrl", null);
elementToDelete.put("drawingUrl", null);
elementToDelete.put("fromFirebase", true);
elementToDelete.put("imageUrl", null);
elementToDelete.put("text", "");
elementToDelete.put("videoUrl", "https://........"); //Add the exact URL
docRef.update("diaryUploadModelList", FieldValue.arrayRemove(elementToDelete));
```

If you don't know the entire data of the document, it won't work.

Another option might be to read the document, modify the diaryUploadModelList in memory, and write the modified diaryUploadModelList back to the document.

Comment: thank you so much I will try this hope it works!!!!

Comment: It will work for sure if do exactly what I wrote in my answer. Give it a try and keep me posted.